# Creating Users and Roles while seeding DB using EF code first

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to seed DB with users every of which can have List. How could I add Roles List {1, 2, 3} (i.e adding Role of "Admin", "User"... to every user) in code (ie. in place I use ***SelectMany*** func):

```
public class Role
{
    public Role(string roleName, int roleType)
    {
        this.RoleName = roleName;
        this.RoleType = roleType;

    }
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int RoleType { get; set; }

}
public class User
{
    [Key]        
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[User UserId={0}, Name={1}, Age={2},    RolesCount={3}]", UserId, Name, Age, Roles.Count);
    }

}

public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      //            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(r => r.Users)
      //                .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("UserId").MapRightKey("RoleId")
      //                     .ToTable("UserRole"));
        Database.SetInitializer(new ContextInitialiser()) ;
    }


}

public class ContextInitialiser: DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UserContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(UserContext context)
    {
        CreateRole("Admin", 1, context);
        CreateRole("SuperUser", 2, context);
        CreateRole("User", 3, context);
        CreateUser("Vovan Super", 31, context.Roles.SelectMany(r => r, (role, user) => new List<Role> (role) ));
        context.Users.ForEachAsync(  Console.WriteLine );
        base.Seed(context);         
    }

    private void CreateUser(string name, int age, List<Role> roles, UserContext ctx)
    {
        ctx.Users.Add(new User {Name = name, Age = age, Roles = roles }  );
    }
    private void CreateRole(string roleName, int roleType, UserContext ctx)
    {
        ctx.Roles.Add(new Role(roleName, roleType));
    }

}
```

Comment: so, you do not prefer to `foreach` to traverse through the list of users and adding `User` and `Admin` roles to each user, right?

Comment: Well, in seed I created 3 roles, and want to assing some of those to some users (i.e User' having List of Roles); so after first 3 lines of seed roles are suposed to be in context and I want to add (all 3 roles) to new user I am creating (actually mostly question about using SelectMany func in the scope and other graceful solutions people can present :))

Comment: Removed template text

Answer (score 0):

```
var roles = new List<Role>()
{
new Role("Admin", 1),
new Role("SuperUser", 2),
new Role("User", 1)
};
ctx.Roles.AddRange(roles);
ctx.Users.Add(new User {Name = "Vovan Super", Age = 31, Roles = roles }  );
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

should do it.

Comment: Ok, it's :) but what would be your idea about the workflow as described, i,e : we add set of roles to DbContext and instantly extract them from it to add to User, like I tried to use SelectMany; basicaly, that whole was more of a question about LINQ, and nice techniques to use it (and paticulalry SelectMany func which I find most dificult to understand)

Comment: Since you are using dropcreatealways strategy i did not see why would you need to query you already have all the role available, i would simply write a where query to select a subset of role if i do not need to assign all role to all user, since you are using role type (i m assuming this will be unique) it would be best to query on basis of it.

Comment: I think context.Roles.SelectMany should be context.Roles.Local.SelectMany, the first query the database the second the local changes not yet commited to db